# How to concatenate elements in XSLT

Tags: xslt

input:

```
    <A>
<T1>
<element1>e1</element1>
<element2>e2</element2>
<element3>e3</element3>
<element5>e5</element5>
</T1>
<T1>
<element4>e4</element4>
</T1>


<T1>
<element1>e1</element1>
<element2>e2</element2>
<element3>e3</element3>
<element5>e5</element5>
</T1>

<T1>
<element1>e1</element1>
<element2>e2</element2>
<element3>e3</element3>
<element5>e5</element5>
</T1>
<T1>
<element4>e4</element4>
</T1>


<T1>
<element4>e4</element4>
</T1>
</A>
```

here we need to perform loop over T1 elements. there are 5 elements present in this T1.we need to concatenate all the elements.we need the below output.Please look into this.

output:

```
<T1>e1e2e3e4e5</T1>
<T1>e1e2e3e5</T1>
<T1>e1e2e3e4e5</T1>
<T1>e4</T1>
```

I tried the below xslt but it is concatenate all the loops.

XSLT:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="A/T1">
      <xsl:value-of select='concat(element1,element2,element3,element4,element5)'/>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="text()"/>
      <xsl:template match="/">
     <T1>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="A/T1"/>
     </T1>

      </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

the above xslt is giving output like.

```
<T1>e1e2e3e5e4e1e2e3e5e1e2e3e5e4e4</T1>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="T1">
      <T1><xsl:value-of select='.'/></T1>
    </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Such a mistake shows that you are new to XSL just as I am, so some basic explanation should not be useless.
I will try to explain why you don't get what you're expecting.

Here:

```
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
```

When you start on your root tag, you write .

```
 <T1>
```

Then you call your template

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="A/T1"/>
```

which applies your xsl:value-of of each T1 tags here:

```
 <xsl:template match="A/T1">
  <xsl:value-of select='concat(element1,element2,element3,element4,element5)'/>
 </xsl:template>
```

your result is then

```
 <T1>e1e2e3e5e4e1e2e3e5e1e2e3e5e4e4
```

and you finally close your tag  :

```
 </T1>
```

So your result is:

```
 <T1>e1e2e3e5e4e1e2e3e5e1e2e3e5e4e4</T1>.
```

What you want is to get the separated content of your T1 tags, so the apply-templates should contain T1 tags definition

just like:

```
 <xsl:template match="A/T1">
   <T1>
     <xsl:value-of select='concat(element1,element2,element3,element4,element5)'/>
   </T1>
 </xsl:template>
```

Then you need not anymore to add T1 in your template root:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="A/T1"/>
 </xsl:template>
```